# How to know which styles files to import when custom theming?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

In the Customizing Themes guide of the Kendo UI two ways are used as examples.

1.

```
    // Import only the PanelBar and Grid styles.
    @import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/panelbar";
    @import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/grid";
```

2.

```
    // styles.scss
    @import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all";
```

My problem is I can't figure out what scss styles I need to import. I have only a Gauge component so adding all seems inefficient and the increased build time is significant.

I tried to find the dependencies on the Gauge component but haven't figured out the pattern. The styles names do not map towards modules or components. What I can see.

Comment: this may help you https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-builder/